# android monkey test exclude some packages

Tags: android, android-monkey

How i run monkey test with exclude some packages？

```
monkey --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --kill-process-after-error --ignore-security-exceptions --throttle 200 -v 20000000
```

I want to test all activities of all packages in my device, but i do not want to test “com.android.camera”.

Answer (score 1):

Use monkey balcklist option **--pkg-blacklist-file**:

1, make a new file called blacklist.txt, contains the package name which you don't want to test，each a line.

2, push this file into device, like /sdcard/blacklist.txt

3, run monkey use balcklist option:

monkey --pkg-blacklist-file /sdcard/blacklist.txt --ignore-crashes --ignore-timeouts --kill-process-after-error --ignore-security-exceptions --throttle 200 -v 20000000

Comment: How can I assign the only application I want to monkey on and exclude some specific activities in the application?